# Get checked and unchecked checkboxes value

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, html

This is my script:

HTML Code:

```
<script>
function pickIt(pId){
    if(document.getElementById(pId).checked==true){
        document.getElementById(pId).checked=false;
    }else{
        document.getElementById(pId).checked = true;
    }
    submitForm();
    return true;
}
</script>
<img src="images/bagua-square.gif" border="0" usemap="#Map2" />
<map name="Map2" id="Map2">
    <area shape="rect" coords="201,14,284,100" onclick="pickIt(1);" />
    <area shape="rect" coords="202,104,284,190" onclick="pickIt(2);" />
    <area shape="rect" coords="202,195,284,283" onclick="pickIt(3);" />
</map>
<div style="display:none;">
    <input type="checkbox" id="1" name="box[]" />
    <input type="checkbox" id="2" name="box[]" />
    <input type="checkbox" id="3" name="box[]" />
</div>
```

PHP Code:

```
<?php
    print_r($_POST['box']);
?>
```

When I click on box id 1 **pickIt()** function turn checkbox 1 to **on**. And the php shows array(0=>'on')

But I also want to get checkbox value which are not checked such that php will show
 array(0=>'on', 1=>'off', 2=>'off')

Actually i want to get all checkboxes with their status **on** and **off** because i am using these id in mysql db to update record status **on** or **off**.
please guide.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Checkboxes send their value if they are checked and are not sent at all if they are not.

You should have:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="1" name="box[]" value="1" />
<input type="checkbox" id="2" name="box[]" value="2"  />
<input type="checkbox" id="3" name="box[]" value="3"  />
```

So the values will be 1, 2 and 3 instead of on, on and on. Then you can tell which ones are checked as they won't all be the same.

If you really want your data structure to be `array(0=>'on', 1=>'off', 2=>'off')` then you could do:

```
$foo = array();
for ($i = 1; $i <= 3; $i++) {
    $foo[$i] = in_array($i, $_GET['box']) ? 'on' : 'off';
}
```

Comment: hmm... little bit closer. Its mean that i have to write two sql queries first to update all records status to set off then to set status to on for only those rows which are in array. :(

Answer (score 1):

A checkbox will be sent to the server (when the form is submitted) only if it's checked, otherwise it's not submitted

also change

```
onclick="pickIt('1');" /
```

Comment: well i have changed to onclick="pickIt('1');" but it still show the old result.

Comment: Actually i want to get all checkboxes with their status on and off because i am using these id in mysql db to update record status on or off. please guide.

Answer (score 0):

Two options:

1. Make hidden fields per checkbox and set the value to 0 or 1 with javascript when you (un)check the checkbox. Then ignore the "on" values in your `$_POST`.
2. Php must know how many (and which) checkboxes there are, so the `$_POST` values that are missing are unchecked boxes. You could do this with a for loop.

Comment: "Php must know how many (and which) checkboxes there are" — only if you tell it. That information isn't in the submitted form data.

Comment: "the $_POST values that are missing are unchecked boxes." — Since they all have the same value, you can only tell how many are missing, not which ones.

Comment: @Quentin: 
1: True, but that's why Form caching is so useful :)
2: Sorry, I mean the $_POST keys. The keys all differ, do they?

Comment: — Not unless they have different `value`s, which they don't.